# Typescript issue with export type

Tags: typescript

I tried compiling an entry TS file and the following issue occured:

```
> tsc --project ./tsconfig.build.json

src/index.ts:2:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

2 export type { Icon } from './component/Button';
  ~~~~~~

src/index.ts:2:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2 export type { Icon } from './component/Button';
              ~

src/index.ts:2:27 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2 export type { Icon } from './component/Button';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The `index.ts` file content is as follows:

```
export { default as Button, Size, ButtonStyle, colors } from './component/Button';
export type { Icon } from './component/Button';
```

The `tsconfig.build.json` file content is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

For files that do not have `export type {xxx}` in the `index.ts`, they are compiled successfully. And if I remove the `export type { Icon } from './component/Button'` from this file, the issue disappear. However, i need those objects in another files.

Any idea?